# Gridview, change visible values

Tags: c#, datagridview, visual-studio-2005

I have a gridview which values from a database are bound to. There are values stored one of the cells in each row as follows:

1

2

3

4

What would the best method be to change those values not in the database but only for what is viewed to

Q1

Mid year

Q3

End Year

Comment: Just have a look at the rowdatabound event, or the TemplateColumn type. I think you could achieve it with each of these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys but I was able to get it using this:

```
    protected string QuarterConvert(object strValue)
    {
        string retString = "";

        switch (Convert.ToString(strValue))
        {
            case "1":
                retString = "Q1";
                break;
            case "2":
                retString = "Mid-Year";
                break;
            case "3":
                retString = "Q3";
                break;
            case "4":
                retString = "Year-End";
                break;
            default:
                break;

        }
        return retString;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dataGridView.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = desiredValue
dataGridView.Rows[1].Cells[0].Value = desiredValue
dataGridView.Rows[2].Cells[0].Value = desiredValue
dataGridView.Rows[3].Cells[0].Value = desiredValue
```

or you can just loop through them. you can access individual peace of data of gridView Like this `nameOfGridView.Rows[desiredRow].Cells[desiredColumn].Value`

Answer (score 0):

You can try it in CellFormatting event ...

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellFormatting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellFormatting
    Dim sHeader As String = DataGridView1.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name

    If ucase(sHeader) = "QUARTER" Then '-------> change this with yours
        If e IsNot Nothing Then
            If e.Value IsNot Nothing Then
                Try
                    Select case e.Value
                        Case 1 : e.Value = "Q1"
                        Case 2 : e.Value = "Mid Year"
                        Case 3 : e.Value = "Q2"
                        Case 4 : e.Value = "End Year"
                    End Select
                    e.FormattingApplied = True
                Catch ex As FormatException
                    e.Value = ""
                End Try
            End If
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```